# How can I create a shortcut to zleaf to run experiments using ztree?

Tags: ztree

I am learning ztree (Zurich Toolbox for Readymade Economic Experiments) from scratch. Actually, I have no problems with understanding how those experiments are built and moreover, the programming is very basic. Unfortunately I struggle with creating a shortcut to zleaf, which is necessary to test the experiments on my own computer. Has anyone experiences with ztree/zleaf and may help me?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: There is no code to share in this case because the ztree file contains all the codes, which are necessary for the experiment. I have to create a shortcut to zleaf to run the experiment and this is where I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you can right click `zleaf.exe` and create shortcut there, like a regular windows executable. Then you can go to properties of it and add necessary parameters to run zleaf.

Alternatively you can use command line interface to run `zleaf.exe` with certain parameters, without creating a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sometimes the task is easier than one assumed.